# Microsoft bot framework Probelms with WebChat and Messenger

Tags: frameworks, bots

I deployed my bot to azure ,and to messenger channel  .
The bot works fine on emulator , while , video card do not work on web-chat and messenger .

Also , I created an adaptive form card so the user can send data , it works fine on  emulator , but 
web-chat and messenger it show up but when trying to submit it show code error .

Here is the code for my video card :

```
  public static VideoCard GetVideoCard()
        {
            var videoCard = new VideoCard
            {
                Title = "Big Buck Bunny",
                Subtitle = "by the Blender Institute",
                Text = "Big Buck Bunny (code-named Peach) is a short computer-animated comedy film by the Blender Institute",
                //Image = new ThumbnailUrl
                //{
                //    Url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c5/Big_buck_bunny_poster_big.jpg/220px-Big_buck_bunny_poster_big.jpg",
                //},
                Media = new List<MediaUrl>
                {
                    new MediaUrl()
                    {
                        Url = "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4",
                    },
                },
                Buttons = new List<CardAction>
                {
                    new CardAction()
                    {
                        Title = "Learn More",
                        Type = ActionTypes.OpenUrl,
                        Value = "https://peach.blender.org/",
                    },
                },
            };

            return videoCard;
        } .
```

the form card (u can see it by copy past this code to https://adaptivecards.io/designer/)  :

```
{
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "version": "1.0",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "ColumnSet",
            "columns": [
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "width": 2,
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "text": "Get In Touch",
                            "weight": "Bolder",
                            "size": "Medium"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "text": "We are interested in advenced technology, we are interested in your business, we are interested in you.\n",
                            "isSubtle": true,
                            "wrap": true
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "text": "Don't worry, we'll never share or sell your information.",
                            "isSubtle": true,
                            "wrap": true,
                            "size": "Small"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "text": "Your name",
                            "wrap": true
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "Input.Text",
                            "placeholder": "Full name",
                            "id": "name",
                            "spacing": "Medium"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "text": "Your email",
                            "wrap": true
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "Input.Text",
                            "id": "email",
                            "placeholder": "youremail@example.com",
                            "style": "Email"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "text": "Subject"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "Input.Text",
            "placeholder": "message",
            "id": "message",
            "isMultiline": true
        }
    ],
    "actions": [
        {
            "type": "Action.Submit",
            "title": "Submit",
            "id": "submitid"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the Video Card , I have fixed it , the only one probelm is facebook is not rendering the card as it suppose to be  :

sample on FB :

[image]
Sample on webchat

[image]